# Magento if attribute value is x or y then show custom block

Tags: php, if-statement, magento, attributes, intersection

On view.phtml, i am trying to get the custom block "console" to display if the value of the attribute platform is either "xbox", "playstation" or "nintendo".

I got the code working for xbox, but how can i solve it so that the block is displayed it the value instead is playstation or nintendo?

Br,
Tobias

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('platform') == "xbox"): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('console')->toHtml() ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want the same block for any of the consoles? I suggest a [switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Replace the if statement you wrote with this:

```
switch($_product->getAttributeText('platform')){
  case "xbox" :
  case "nintendo" :
  case "playstation" :
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('console')->toHtml();
    break;
  default :
    //here you can put a default other block or show nothing or whatever you want to do if the product is not a console
}
```

Now you can add more consoles by adding more `case "other console" :` statements.

There are other ways. You could create an array of all consoles from the attribute values and then use [inArray();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - that might be better for the general case if your client adds more consoles to the attribute via the Magento admin.

**EDITED ** following the comment below

If the attribute 'platform' is multiselect then `$_product->getAttributeText('platform')` will be string if one item is selected but if there are multiple items selected it will be an array. So you need to handle a single variable that can be string or array. Here we will convert string to array and use [PHP's handy array_intersect() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

I suggest:

```
$platformSelection = $_product->getAttributeText('platform');
if (is_string($platformSelection))
{
    //make it an array
    $platformSelection = array($platformSelection); //type casting of a sort
}

//$platformSelection is now an array so:

//somehow know what the names of the consoles are:
$consoles = array('xbox','nintendo','playstation');

if(array_intersect($consoles,$platformSelection)===array())
{
    //then there are no consoles selected
    //here you can put a default other block or show nothing or whatever you want to do if the product is not a console
}
else
{
    //there are consoles selected
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('console')->toHtml();
}
```

Note that the array_intersect() function compares the array elements strictly that is `===` so it is case sensitive and the function returns an empty array `array()` if there is no intersection.

Comment: Hi Malachy, i can see that this is working. However, the attribute platform is a "multiple select" attribute, meaning that some products may have both "xbox" and "playstation". And then the block "console" is not displayed. Have any tips on how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same block for either of those 3 values, this should do it:

```
<?php 
$productAttribute = $_product->getAttributeText('platform');
if ($productAttribute == "xbox" || $productAttribute == "playstation" || $productAttribute == "nintendo"): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('console')->toHtml() ?><?php endif; ?>
```

If you want different blocks depending on the value, this should do it:

```
<?php
$productAttribute = $_product->getAttributeText('platform');
switch ($productAttribute){
  case "xbox":
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('xbox')->toHtml();
break;
  case "playstation":
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('playstation')->toHtml();
break;
  case "nintendo":
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('nintendo')->toHtml();
break;
}
?>
```